# Slythe and Krystin missing in Undercellar

Tags: baldurs-gate, baldurs-gate-enhanced

I am playing Baldur's Gate Enhanced Edition v2.3.67.3 on Steam and I have the "Slythe and Krystin" quest where I am supposed to fight them in the Undercellar. I entered the Undercellar through the Sewer but the two are missing. I found a video where they were in the middle of the Undercellar but they are not at this place nor at any other there. **Are there alternative locations where I should search for Slythe and Krystin?**